# Creating an admin permissions section in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I've created a couple of pages they are users, groups and permissions.
I would like the admin to be able to create groups and set what those groups can do via the permissions page.

So on the permissions page I would have a list of things a user could do e.g.: add content, delete content.

And if I check the add content box then the group can only add content and not delete content.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know where to go to look for information on how to go about it. I've already got my database set up and I'm thinking maybe sessions and routes is the way to go, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks is the way to go for something this complex. I'm working on a very similar project for my work (a dashboard to do different things based on User Role/Permissions) and I found it incredibly difficult to manage without the use of a framework. I would highly recommend Cartalyst/Sentry for this. It turns complex database operations like checking permissions, update permissions, creating groups etc into simple one. Here is a link to the manual:

[Cartalyst/Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry)

It has a database backend already created (and modifiable) for you, so you simply follow the installation instructions and go over the documentation to get a better understanding. In your example, it would be as simple as creating a group and it's permissions:

```
// Define permissions (1 is allowed, 0 is not allowed)
$permissions = array('content.create' => 1, 'content.delete' => 1, etc etc...));
$group = Sentry::createGroup(array('name' => 'Admin', 'permissions' => $permissions));
```

Creating a user and adding them to the group:

```
$user = Sentry::createUser(array('email' => 'test@test.com', 'first_name' => ..., etc));
$group = Sentry::findGroupByName('Admin');
$user->addGroup($group);
```

And then checking their permissions during routing:

```
$user = Sentry::check(); // Aka get the current user.
if($user->hasAccess('content.create'){ 
    // Continue
} else {
    // Redirect to error page, etc
}
```

Now that's a brief overview of the system, and I assume you know how to use controllers and routes, but play around with it and I'm sure you'll come to see how powerful this Framework is when working with Laravel.

Hope that helps!

Then checking whether or not a user